# Copy the values from another column if the column A has null values

Tags: python, dataframe

How to copy the values from column A to column B, if the column B has null values.

DATA:

```
   A        B      
12525    1FWE23   
14654        
24798         
38945         
46456    46485     
AD545    45346     
A5D66
```

EXPECTED :

```
   A        B      
12525    1FWE23   
14654    14654    
24798    24798    
38945    38945     
46456    46485     
AD545    45346     
A5D66    A5D66
```

Comment: are the blank values in B nan? or ""?

Comment: The values in column B are ""

Answer (score 1):

If your blank values are nan, you can just use [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df['B'] = df['B'].fillna(df['A'])

   A        B      
12525    1FWE23   
14654    14654    
24798    24798    
38945    38945     
46456    46485     
AD545    45346     
A5D66    A5D66
```

If they are empty strings, you can [`replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) them with nan and do the same:

```
import numpy as np
df['B'] = df['B'].replace("", np.nan).fillna(df['A'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If empty values are None:

`df.B.fillna(df.A, inplace=True)`

If empty values are empty string `("")`:

`df.loc[df['B'] == '', 'B'] = df.loc[df['B'] == '', 'A']`

Answer (score -1):

```
df['B'] = df['B'].fillna(df['A'])
```

The above code fixed the issue for me by replacing the blank values in the column B with the column A values